# how to create an instance of class and its properties with user input in c#

Tags: c#, class, object

I have a class...

```
Class Logins
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }   
}
```

and my main function is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logins User1 = new Logins() { Name = "mark", Contact = "134" };

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", User1.Name,User1.Contact);
}
```

Right now i am hard coding the instances of this class and also assigning it the properties at the same time. How do I make the user to input values so that  a new instance gets created and also user can be able to input the values (Name and Contact)?

Like if  a 2nd user comes it can automatically instantiates the class with user input like `Logins User1 = new Logins()` and then asks the user to input the values as well
`{ Name = "mark", Contact = "134" }`;

..hopefully i was able to put this question clearly.
I have already tried to look for the solution but could not find.Please help .
Thanks.

Comment: Simple user input i know and i also know that if the class is already instantiated i can ask for the user input withe the name of the object.propertyname .example in my case  if  have instantiate a class with new object "Logins user2 =new user();   Annd then i can ask user to input name and i can read that with "user2.Name=Console.raedLine().But i would like to know how to instantiate the class also with user input and once instantiated it asks for the objects properties also.Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @ruralindian Okay, show us the way you know how to get user input, please.

Comment: Please have a look

Comment: if you want to instantiate the class with values then use the constructor and pass in the parameters you want to use to instantiate the class with. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: @Sorceri I am looking for an option if the class can be instantiated with user input,if possible.And thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8) method to get information from the user (it returns a string representing the user's input up to when they hit the `Enter` key), and you can store the result in a variable. You can then use this variable to set the values for the class you're creating.

So, given this class:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }   
}
```

You could write code like:

```
Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter your Surname: ");
string surname = Console.ReadLine();

User user1 = new User() { Name = name, Surname = surname };

Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0} {1}.", user1.Name, user1.Surname);
```

---

Now, looking at that code above, it seems a little repetitive. We can wrap both the `Console.Write` and `Console.ReadLine` calls into a single method that takes in a `string` that represents the prompt for the user, and which returns a `string`, which is the user's input:

```
private static string GetUserInput(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And now we can cut the lines of code needed to get user input from 4 to 2:

```
string name = GetUserInput("Enter your name: ");
string surname = GetUserInput("Enter your surname: ");
```

---

And, in fact, we can get really crazy and reduce the code to instantiate a new `User` class to one line, where we call our method and use it's return value when creating the object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    User user1 = new User 
    {
        Name = GetUserInput("Enter your name: "),
        Surname = GetUserInput("Enter your surname: ")
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0} {1}.", user1.Name, user1.Surname);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your help.I was confused.You have elaborated in a simple way.Thanks again @Rufus L